# AppExchange - Does it have its own API for data like analytics?

Tags: api, appexchange

When you have a package listed on the AppExchange you get some analytics that you can view when logged into the publishing console.

[image]

As an example (although an anemic one )

I tried searching and could not find anything which leads me to believe the answer to my question is no.

**Question**: Is there an API that exists where this information can be retrieved and brought into another org for additional analysis?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Better? If not suggestions?

Comment: Hoping that someone has some undocumented or not well documented knowledge on this one....

Comment: Funny enough, I typed in "appexchange api" and came up with [this document](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/sforce_API.pdf?major=142). Read it for about 10 seconds and realized it was not what I thought it was.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I did that to. Talk about the way back machine. Interesting read though.